# Jquery remove string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to remove some string from a string in Jquery but it doesnt work and my variable still looks the same.

```
var classes = $("body").attr('class');
alert('.side-nav' + classes);
classes = classes.replace('.side-navblog parent-  page- how-it-works-','');
$(".side-nav" + classes).css("display","block");
```

When I alert classes after it has been replaces, there is still .side-navblog parent-  page- how-it-works- in the string which I do not want.

Comment: please share the alerted value

Comment: Why not use `.removeClass`?

Comment: also the class attribute value may not have `.` so `'.side-navblog parent-  page- how-it-works-'` should be `'side-navblog parent-  page- how-it-works-'`

Comment: The first alerted value is .side-navblog parent-  page- how-it-works-applications

The alerted value that I want is  applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
classes = classes.replace('.side-navblog parent- page- how-it-works-','');
                                                      ^^ double space here
```

or try a regex

```
classes = classes.match(/how-it-works-([^$\s]*)/)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try regular expression,

```
classes = classes.replace(/.side-navblog|parent-|page-|how-it-works-/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

What I can figure out from your comment is you have put to spaces just before 'page-'. Other than it should work fine.

`classes = classes.replace('blog parent- page- how-it-works-','');`

Check out here - http://jsfiddle.net/Fb367/